# How to render a panel with some Error message

Tags: apex

I am new to Salesforce, so i'd be glad, if I could get some help.

I am having a custom button, when I will click it, it'll check some condition, if it satisfied, then it will render a panel with an error message.

VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Save" onComplete="refreshTab({!isError});" />
```

JavaCsript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           function refreshTab(isError) {
               if (!isError) {
                   sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(refreshTabById);
               }
           }
           function refreshTabById(tabId) {
               if(sforce && sforce.console && sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
                   sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId.id, true);
               }
           }      

       </script>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference doSomething(){
    isError = false;

    Date todayDate = System.today();

    system.debug('Todat Date'+todayDate );
    system.debug('Contact_Date'+caseObj.Next_Customer_Contact_Date__c); // CaseObject is an instance of an Object.


    if (caseObj.Next_Customer_Contact_Date__c < todayDate) {

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                            ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                            'Next Customer Contact Date must not be in the past'));

         isError = true;                
         return null;        
    }         

    if(caseObj.Current_Situation__c != null){               
        caseObj.Current_Situation__c= caseObj.Current_Situation__c.substring(0, Math.min(caseObj.Current_Situation__c.length(), 255));
    }

    if(caseObj.Next_Steps__c != null){
        caseObj.Next_Steps__c = caseObj.Next_Steps__c.substring(0, Math.min(caseObj.Next_Steps__c.length(), 255));                
    }
    string myText = String.valueOf(
                    'Next Customer Contact Date: ' + caseObj.Next_Customer_Contact_Date__c.format())
                    + '\n\nCurrent Situation: ' + caseObj.Current_Situation__c 
                    + '\n\nNext Steps: ' + caseObj.Next_Steps__c;

    // Feeding to chatter
    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, caseObj.Id, myText);  

    try{
        update caseObj;
    }catch (Exception ex) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                            ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                            ex.getMessage()));
        isError = true;                        
    }       

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use apex page messages

> ```
> <apex:pageMessages id="msg"/>
> ```

and on the button click rerender it.

There are two way to display message on visualforce page from controller

1. Normal Case:

to display simple message follow this

ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.info,constantClass.'Hello'));

1. Exception Case:

Try {

// your code

}catch(Exception e)

{

ApexPages.addMessages(e) ;

}

Please mind that there two method I have explained above

ApexPages.addMessage(pMessage)

& 
ApexPages.addMessages(pAPEX_OBJECT)

Comment: I tried with <apex:pageMessage />, but somehow, it didn't work. So for time being I want to use OutputPanel to display the message.

Comment: I suspect id of the apex page messages tag is not getting detected in your case. Have you tried rerendering using {!$Component.msg} in the rerender attribute of your command button ?

Comment: {!$Component.msg} it worked

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
 <apex:page controller="message">
  <apex:pagemessages />
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageblock > 
  <apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Save" />
   <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!isError}">
     <apex:pageMessage summary="This is a pageMessage" severity="error" strength="3"/>
   </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:pageblock > 
</apex:form >
```

```
public class message{
public boolean isError{get;set;}
public message()
{
  isError=false;
}
public PageReference doSomething() {


    if (condition) {

         isError = true;                

    }   
  return null; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an `id` for your `outputPanel` and introduce a `rerender` attribute to your `commandButton`
VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Save" rerender="myPanel" />
<apex:outputPanel id="myPanel" layout="block" rendered="{!isError}">
   Error should go here in this panel
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The platform has an error handling framework built in that is the easiest thing to use. Also if you do not use it you are in danger of failing to report errors to your user such as errors added in triggers.

With this in your page:

```
<apex:pageMessages/>
```

your controller will be able to add an error using code like this:

```
public PageReference doSomething() {
    if (isError) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,
                'Error message'));
        return null;        
    }
    return ...;
}
```

and the `apex:pageMessages` tag will output this error message and any others.

Comment: I used <apex:pageMessage />. It appears that the pageMessages tag is not being rendered on this page within Service Cloud.  I changed the ID of the pageMessages tag on the page and liked in Firebug for an element with that ID and I couldn’t find it.  I thought the outputPanel could perform the same function.

Comment: @SFDCGeek I don't know why it isn't working for you. If you are just starting out with Salesforce, figuring out why the normal approach isn't working might make more sense than creating your own work-around mechanism. Perhaps you should post the page and controller where you tried to use apex:pageMessages? (You did try apex:pageMessages and not apex:pageMessage?)

Comment: yes I used <apex:pageMessages />.

I will update the controller and Page in my question